# XmlDocument from google analytics to flat file c#

Tags: c#, xmldocument, google-analytics-api

Using C# I have extracted data from Google Analytics Data API and have got it in an xmldocument. From that point I want to export it to flat file format (txt file). I am trying to use the xmlnode class to write out element attribute values within the 'entry' elements but cant do it. XML code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dxp="http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-    /spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <id>https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:xxxxxxxxx&amp;dimensions=ga:date,ga:hostname&amp;metrics=ga:visits,ga:newVisits,ga:visitBounceRate,ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:itemQuantity&amp;start-date=2012-09-20&amp;end-date=2012-09-26&amp;start-index=1&amp;max-results=1000</id>
  <updated>2012-09-27T08:08:53.621Z</updated>
  <title type="text">Google Analytics Data for Profile xxxxxxxxx</title>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:xxxxxxxxx&amp;dimensions=ga:date,ga:hostname&amp;metrics=ga:visits,ga:newVisits,ga:visitBounceRate,ga:transactions,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:itemQuantity&amp;start-date=2012-09-20&amp;end-date=2012-09-26&amp;start-index=1&amp;max-results=1000" />
  <author>
    <name>Google Analytics</name>
  </author>
  <generator>Google Analytics</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults>49</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>1000</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <dxp:aggregates>
    <dxp:metric name="ga:visits" type="integer" value="942258" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:newVisits" type="integer" value="393698" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:visitBounceRate" type="percent" value="26.960025810340692" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:transactions" type="integer" value="328" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:transactionRevenue" type="currency" value="427646.331187" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:itemQuantity" type="integer" value="322" />
  </dxp:aggregates>
  <dxp:containsSampledData>true</dxp:containsSampledData>
  <dxp:dataSource>
    <dxp:property name="ga:profileId" value="xxxxxxxxx" />
    <dxp:property name="ga:webPropertyId" value="UA-33036832-1" />
    <dxp:property name="ga:accountName" value="TCO-UK-TC.com-[thomascook.com]" />
    <dxp:tableId>ga:xxxxxxxxx</dxp:tableId>
    <dxp:tableName>ThomasCook UK - Analytics Extract (VP /search)</dxp:tableName>
  </dxp:dataSource>
  <dxp:endDate>2012-09-26</dxp:endDate>
  <dxp:startDate>2012-09-20</dxp:startDate>
  <entry>
    <id>https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:xxxxxxxxx&amp;ga:date=20120920&amp;ga:hostname=87.248.112.8&amp;start-date=2012-09-20&amp;end-date=2012-09-26</id>
    <updated>2012-09-27T08:08:53.621Z</updated>
    <title type="text">ga:date=20120920 | ga:hostname=87.248.112.8</title>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.google.com/analytics" />
    <dxp:dimension name="ga:date" value="20120920" />
    <dxp:dimension name="ga:hostname" value="87.248.112.8" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:visits" type="integer" value="3" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:newVisits" type="integer" value="3" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:visitBounceRate" type="percent" value="100.0" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:transactions" type="integer" value="0" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:transactionRevenue" type="currency" value="0.0" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:itemQuantity" type="integer" value="0" />
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:xxxxxxxxx&amp;ga:date=20120920&amp;ga:hostname=alpha.thomascook.com&amp;start-date=2012-09-20&amp;end-date=2012-09-26</id>
    <updated>2012-09-27T08:08:53.621Z</updated>
    <title type="text">ga:date=20120920 | ga:hostname=alpha.thomascook.com</title>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.google.com/analytics" />
    <dxp:dimension name="ga:date" value="20120920" />
    <dxp:dimension name="ga:hostname" value="alpha.thomascook.com" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:visits" type="integer" value="160" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:newVisits" type="integer" value="109" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:visitBounceRate" type="percent" value="21.25" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:transactions" type="integer" value="0" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:transactionRevenue" type="currency" value="0.0" />
    <dxp:metric name="ga:itemQuantity" type="integer" value="0" />
  </entry>
  ....so on.....
```

In the code below I need to change it to locate the entry elements, but can't find it. Using "/entry" yields nothing.

```
XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmld.NameTable);
xmlnsm.AddNamespace("dxp", "http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009");
xmlnsm.AddNamespace("openSearch", "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/");
xmlnsm.AddNamespace("gd", "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005");

foreach (XmlNode xmlnd in xmld.SelectNodes("//dxp:dimension", xmlnsm))
{
    DimVal = xmlnd.Attributes["value"].Value.ToString();
    DimName = xmlnd.Attributes["name"].Value.Replace("ga:", "");
    // ...
}
```

I could be missing a namespace. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileToLoad); //or XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
XNamespace dxp = "http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009";
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

var result =
    xDoc.Descendants(ns + "entry")
    .Select(e => new
    {
        Dimension = e.Descendants(dxp + "dimension")
                     .ToDictionary(d => d.Attribute("name").Value, d => d.Attribute("value").Value),
        Metric = e.Descendants(dxp + "metric")
                  .ToDictionary(d => d.Attribute("name").Value, d => d.Attribute("value").Value)
    })
    .ToList();
```

**Print the result:**

```
foreach(var entry in result)
{
    foreach (var dim in entry.Dimension) 
          Console.WriteLine(dim.Key + " = " + dim.Value);
    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach (var met in entry.Metric) 
          Console.WriteLine(met.Key + " = " + met.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("---------------");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in getting all of the dxp:dimension elements you could use

```
GetElementsByTagName("dimension", "http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009")
```

instead of

```
SelectNodes("//dxp:dimension", xmlnsm)
```

If you're intent on using SelectNodes, I think you need another / ("///dxp:dimension").

Specifically for your case you can do:

```
foreach(XmlElement ele in xmld.GetElementsByTagName("element"))
{
    foreach(XmlElement dim in ele.GetElementsByTagName("dimension", "http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009")
    {
        // Do w/e w/ the element
    }
    foreach(XmlElement met in ele.GetElementsByTagName("metric", "http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009")
    {
        // Do w/e w/ the element
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to return all dxp:dimension (x2) and dxp:metric (x6) attribute values per <entry>. This is essentially a table row.

Comment: @user1704232 So you want to iterate through the dxp:dimension and dxp:metric elements on each entry element? (i.e. one foreach for the entry elements and one foreach for the dim/met elements)

Comment: yeah, so i can create delimited lines of the dim/met attribute values to a text file.

Comment: @user1704232 Ok, edited, I assume you know better than I do how to convert the elements into your format (in other words what information you want to extract).

Comment: i haven't tested this but the code looks concise. Will try it out, thank you. I can write out the results to a flat file now which is good, but Google Analytics limits result sets to be 10000 per query. Next challenge is to find the total result set and loop through querying the data how every many times is needed to get the total number of records!